# Generate mobile builds using visual studio for windows, android and iOS

Tags: cordova

Was using Intel XDK tool to build an cordova mobile app. The XDK used to provide .apk , ipa and appxupload files(universal app) for each of the store.
Now that Intel XDK is on an EOL path, I wanted to set up the code in Visual Studio to generate the builds.
I selected BLankCordova app and replaced the www folder. Am able to develop and debug using the emulator.
However how do i generate the builds for windows and android?
In the config file I can specify the name of the app and version, but where to add the publisher ID
Similarly for android , how to choose the developer certificate?

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can get more information about visual studio and cordova in http://taco.visualstudio.com/

Answer (score 1):

To be able to correctly package and sign Windows apps there are few things required:

- A signing certificate
- Identity details matching the provided signing certificate

I am not sure if the options are there in visual studio. But u can do in command line using (ex- Windows platform)-

```
cordova build -- --packageCertificateKeyFile="platforms\windows\CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx" --packageThumbprint="ABCABCABCABC123123123123"
```

Alternatively, these values could be specified using a build configuration file **(build.json)** using CLI (--buildConfig). A sample build configuration file:

```
{
"windows": {
    "debug": {
        "packageCertificateKeyFile": "platforms\\windows\\CordovaApp_TemporaryKey.pfx"
    },
    "release": {
        "packageCertificateKeyFile": "c:\\path-to-key\\keycert.pfx",
        "packageThumbprint": "ABCABCABCABC123123123123",
        "publisherId": "CN=FakeCorp.com, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US"
    }
}}
```

For creating certificate keys -

`certutil -user -p PASSWORD -importPFX FakeCorp.com.pfx`

NOTE : Signing is required for distributing and installing Windows Store apps. This process is normally handled by Visual Studio when you deploy a package for release.

Please refer Platform Guides of cordova like [this(windows)](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/win8/index.html#signing-an-app).
Signing an Android App in cordova is given [here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#signing-an-app).

Comment: After generating the appxupload file, when I try to install in my phone am getting the error 'Failed to start deployment, package count not be opened'.
Also the ps script to install in windows desktop is failing with the error :
"Unable to install the bundle file because it does not have an appropriate application architecture for x64 architecture"
Tried the steps of setting the minversion to 10.0.0.0, but still getting the error
Can you please guide me where am going wrong?